# How does GCC (not clang) make this optimization deciding that a store to one struct member couldn't affect a member of another?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization, strict-aliasing

This is the code in question:

```
struct Cell
{
    Cell* U;
    Cell* D;
    void Detach();
};

void Cell::Detach()
{
    U->D = D;
    D->U = U;
}
```

clang-14 -O3 produces:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]         <-- rax = U
mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]     <-- rcx = D
mov     qword ptr [rax + 8], rcx     <-- U->D = D
mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]     <-- this queries the D field again
mov     qword ptr [rcx], rax         <-- D->U = U
```

gcc 11.2 -O3 produces almost the same, but leaves out one `mov`:

```
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
mov     QWORD PTR [rdx+8], rax
mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
```

Clang reads the D field twice, while GCC reads it only once and re-uses it. Apparently GCC is not afraid of the first assignment changing anything that has an impact on the second assignment. I'm trying to understand if/when this is allowed.

Checking correctness gets a bit complicated when U or D point at themselves, each other and/or the same target.

My understanding is that the shorter code of GCC is correct if it is guaranteed that the pointers point at the beginning of a Cell (never inside it), regardless of which Cell it is.

Following this line of thought further, this is the case when a) Cells are always aligned to their size, and b) no custom manipulation of such a pointer occurs (referencing and arithmetic are fine).
I suspect case a) is guaranteed by the compiler, and case b) would require invoking undefined behavior of some sort, and as such can be ignored.
This would explain why GCC allows itself this optimization.

Is my reasoning correct? If so, why does clang not make the same optimization?

Comment: I think, in the C++ specification, many part of optimization is implementation-dependent.  When some compiler vendor apply some optimization, it is not enforcing other compiler vendor to implement their way. Also, some optimization technology may be patented.

Comment: Oh, I have to note that as GCC is copyleft, patent scenario will not be the case.

Comment: In addition, as clang is LLVM family, it compiles to LLVM IR first, then compiles according to your system architecture. Although it has advantage in some way, it reduces the possibility of optimization for device-specific way.

Comment: @K.R.Park The assembly did not change for `-march-zenv3`

Comment: The only reason to reload would be if there was any worry about aliasing. However, the first store (`U->D = D;`)  cannot modify the value of `U` in the second assignment (`D->U = U;`) , because they write to disjoint members, so they cannot possibly alias. The value of `D` in the second assignment could theoretically be affected by the first assignment, but only if `this == U`, so the first assignment is self-assignment of the `D`-member, which is a nop.

Comment: @K.R.Park: GCC transforms through GIMPLE, an SSA form that serves the same purpose for it as LLVM-IR does for LLVM.  But yes, that step is one way that information from the source can be lost, leading to missed optimizations.  (Not correctness bugs, of course; LLVM-IR has to be able to represent everything LLVM needs to at least maintain correctness.)

Comment: @EOF: That sounds like it's pretty much an answer to the part about how GCC makes the optimization.  And by obvious extension, clearly clang doesn't manage to follow that chain of logic, or doesn't try at some of the steps in the first place, so it doesn't prove the illegality of aliasing even when `-fstrict-aliasing` is in effect.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Is LLVM capable of expressing the fact that a pointer can compare equal to another without belonging to the same aliasing set?  Both clang and an LLVM-based implementation of Rust seem to assume that if X is observed to be equal to Y, a compiler may replace accesses to X with accesses to Y, while assuming that accesses to "Y" [the replaced X] won't access anything that Y couldn't be used to access directly.

Comment: @PeterCordes: For that matter, is LLVM capable of expressing the idea that the execution of a side-effect free loop may occur in sequence, deferred, or skipped, but must not be processed n a way that creates nonsensical side effects?  In some cases where code as written wouldn't observe any results of computations performed within a loop, clang will sometimes generate code whose validity relies upon the execution of a loop, but omit the code upon whose execution it is relying.

Answer (score 0):

There are many potential optimizations in C and C++ that are usually safe, but aren't quite sound.  If one regards the `->` operator as being usable to build a standard-layout object without having to use placement new on it first (an abstraction model that is relied upon by a lot of code, whether or not the Standard mandates support), removing the `if (mode)` in the following C and C++ funcitons would be such an optimization.

C version:

```
struct s { int x,y; }; /* Assume int is 4 bytes, and struct is 8 */

void test(struct s *p1, struct s *p2, int mode)
{
    p1->y = 1;
    p2->x = 2;
    if (mode)
        p1->y = 1;            
}
```

C++ version:

```
#include <new>
struct s { int x,y; };
void test(void *vp1, void *vp2, int mode)
{
    if (1)
    {
        struct s* p1 = new (vp1) struct s;
        p1->x = 1;            
    }
    if (1)
    {
        struct s* p2 = new (vp2) struct s;
        p2->y = 2;
    }
    if (mode)
    {
        struct s* p3 = new (vp1) struct s;
        p3->x = 1;            
    }
}
```

The optimization would be correct unless the address in p2 is four bytes higher than p1.  Under the "traditional" abstraction model used in C or C++, if the address of `p1` happens to be `0x1000` and that of `p2` happens to be `0x1004`, the first assignment would cause addresses 0x1000-0x1007 to hold a `struct s`, if it didn't already, whose second member (at address 0x1004) would equal 1.  The second assignment, by overwriting that object, would end its lifetime and cause addresses 0x1004 to 0x100B to hold a `struct s` whose first member would equal 2.  The third assignment, *if executed*, would end the lifetime of that second object and re-create the first.

If the third assignment is executed, there would be an object at address 0x1000 whose second field (at address 0x1004) would hold the readable value 1.  If the assignment is skipped, there would be an object at address 0x1004 whose first field would hold the value 2.  Behavior would be defined in both cases, and a compiler that didn't know which case would apply would have to accommodate both of them by making the value at 0x1004 depend upon `mode`.

As it happens, the authors of clang do not seem to have provided for that corner case, and thus omit the conditional check.  While I think the Standard should use an abstraction model that would allow such optimization, while also supporting the common structure-creation pattern in situations that don't involve weird aliasing corner cases, I don't see any way of interpreting the Standard that would allow for such optimization without allowing compilers to arbitrarily break a large amount of existing code.

I don't think there's any general way of knowing when a decision by gcc or clang not to impose a particular optimization represents a recognition of potential corner cases where the optimization would be incorrect, and an inability to prove that none of them apply, and when it simply represents an oversight which may be "corrected" to as to replace correct behavior with an unsound optimization.

Comment: One seemingly small correction.... you said "end the lifetime of that second object and re-create the first".  The newly created object is in the same location that the first formerly occupied, but it is a new third object; the first object is permanently gone since its storage was reused.

Comment: But that small correction has some consequences.  In particular, `p1` was a pointer which refers to the first object (it must be, because it was used to write the `y` member of that first object).  [There are conditions necessary for using that pointer to refer to the new third object](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8), and those conditions are not met.  You need a new pointer, equal in stored address but which has never been used with the first object, such as created by `p1 = std::launder(p1);`, before the second `p1->y = 1;` will behave correctly.

Comment: While the exact wording of those requirements have changed over the years, I find the prohibition on using `p1` to access the new third object was already in C++03 [basic.life]/6.

Comment: In conclusion, the code snippet in your answer attempts to write to the first object, and in the interesting overlapping scenario that first object no longer exists (its storage has been reused, ending its lifetime) and trying to access its members after the lifetime is ended is UB.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What makes you think the code is trying to write the first object, rather than creating a third new object whose address happens to match that which historically belonged to an object that no longer exists?  Also, since it is common for a project to combine new code that was written to a new language standard, and pre-existing code that was written to an earlier language standard, having a compiler interpret a request to enable new features as an invitation to break the existing code would be far less helpful than having a separate option to specify...

Comment: ...whether a project was free of code that relied upon behavioral guarantees that compilers are no longer required to support.  If a construct had defined behavior under one version of the Standard, and new versions of the Standard would allow compilers to keep processing it the same way, having newer compilers accept the old code but then processing it nonsensically is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: There are two possibilities.  (a) It's trying to write the first object.  UB because that object's lifetime has ended.  (b) It's trying to write a brand-new object that exists at the same address.  UB because the conditions for using a pointer to an old object for access to a new object are not met.  Under either interpretation, it is UB, and that's true going back to at least C++03 (and probably C++98, need someone with a copy of that old Standard to check it), so your deflection about pre-existing code is invalid too.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No code which predates `std::launder` is going to use that function.  You may claim such code never had defined behavior, but it certainly had defined behavior in the years prior to the publication of C++99, and if C++99 didn't provide a workable way of achieving the same semantics it simply failed to accurately describe the language people were using.

Comment: Note that the C++ Standard expressly refrains from defining a category of conformance for programs; it merely attempts to specify when implementations are required to behave meaningfully.  In cases where constructs should obviously be processed in meaningful fashion, but the Standard failed to specify that, compilers would simply behave meaningfully without regard for whether the Standard required them to do so, and the language people actually used supported such constructs without regard for the Standard's failure to mandate such support.

Comment: Surely you mean C++98 not 99?  I challenge you to produce any document specifying behavior for this code.  If it isn't defined in a written specification, then it is not "defined behavior" of the language, only implementation-specific behavior.  And probably continues to work fine on that particular implementation.  But it is a fool's errand to ascribe portability to code older than the first written specifications.

Comment: @BenVoigt: In the language invented by Dennis Ritchie, as documented in 1974, the behavior of `->` was *defined* in terms of the appropriate address computation, all versions of the C and C++ Standards allow implementations to behave in a manner consistent with that, and many practical implementations in fact behave in that fashion.  No version of the C nor C++ Standard has ever sought to specify all of the cases where implementations intended for various purposes should be expected to behave in a manner consistent with the 1974 behavior [since that would vary depending upon the purposes...

Comment: There's a huge amount of C1974 code which is strictly forbidden (ill-formed, diagnostic required) by the C++ Standard.  Take applying `->` to an integer as an example.

Comment: ...for which implementations are intended to be suitable].  Implementations intended for low-level programming would generally behave "In a documented manner characteristic of the environment" when processing actions for which the environment would have a naturally-defined behavior when there was no reason to do otherwise, documenting cases where they deviated from that pattern rather than all the places where they follow it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The authors of C89 and C99 did not view the classification as UB of constructs which many implementations would process meaningfully, and upon which many existing programs relied, as a breaking change.  Instead, they expected that any implementations whose customers would rely upon such constructs would support them, and viewed support for such constructs as a quality-of-implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

Comment: "implementations whose customers would rely upon such constructs" do support them, conditionally.  Try `fno-strict-aliasing`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Note that the authors of C89 didn't have any consensus as to what constructs should be viewed as "forbidden", which is why the Standard allows for the possibility that an implementation which is fed a program which e.g. includes a zero-sized array within a struct may output a diagnostic "The C Standard needlessly forbids the use of zero-sized arrays as address markers, without providing any usable alternative" and then process in useful fashion as though the constraint didn't exist.  If a conforming implementation accepts a source text, even with a diagnostic, that source text...

Comment: ...is a Conforming C Program [even though it wouldn't be a Strictly Conforming C Program].  As for the C++ Standard, it expressly does not define any category of conformance for C++ programs.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does gcc *actually* define the behavior of such constructs when using `-fno-stirct-aliasing`, or merely say that it won't use "aliasing" optimizations but not bother to say that it will regard code that would be affected from such optimizations as though N1570 6.5p7 were omitted?  For most other compilers such a distinction shouldn't matter, but the authors of gcc are adamant that they reserve the right to change without notice the behavior of any constructs that aren't actually defined.

Comment: The standard calls out certain things as "ill-formed".  Even if the toolchain proceeds with compilation after generating the required diagnostic, it is a grave mistake to apply the label "conforming" to an ill-formed program.  "ill-formed" and "well-formed" are most certainly categories of (non-)conformance.

Comment: Also, C++ compilers are not free to accept ill-formed / undefined behavior "as an extension with implementation-defined behavior" in certain contexts.  For example, `consteval` and SFINAE.

Comment: @BenVoigt: C++ was intended to be upwardly-compatible with C, and according to the published Rationale actions characterized as Undefined Behavior, among other things, "identify areas of conforming language extension".  SFINAE does represent a fundamental change to the language which makes it necessary to recognize some constructs as ill-formed, at least in cases where alternative expansions are available, but the C++ Standard from what I recall expressly states that constraints on programs are specified purely as means of indicating compiler compiler obligations and exemptions therefrom...

Comment: ...rather than recognizing any category of conformance for C++ programs.  In C, the Standard applies the term "strictly conforming" to a small number of maximally-portable programs (which among other things excludes all non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations), while describing every source text that is accepted by some C compiler somewhere in the universe, possibly as a "conforming language extension", as a "conforming C Program".  In the absence of aliasing rules, one could define the term "object" in C or "PODS" in C++ in such a way that every region of storage contains...

Comment: ....objects of all types that will fit, changes to any object will affect some or all of the underlying storage contained within it, and changes to any piece of the underlying storage will affect the values of objects containing it, and there would be no need to recognize any notions of object lifetime separate from that of the enclosing storage.  Neither C nor C++ has a coherent abstraction model for whether the evaluation of a construct like `&structPtr->someMember` requires that the storage at `structPtr`'s address be associated with `*structPtr`'s type, ir would create such association.

Comment: Pre-standard dialects of C were agnostic to the existence of such associations, and for purposes of optimization they're a lousy abstraction model.  A far more practical model would examine the question of whether lvalues that are used to access a region of storage have a visible association with a common type and means of access.  If between two accesses to a T a compiler sees both a conversion from `T*` to `U*`, it should recognize accesses to `U*` that also occur between those accesses as possible accesses to the `T*`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Can you inspect the C++ version of the function I just posted to see if it conforms to the requirements for placement new?  Even with the placement new operators, clang still doesn't recognize the need for the `if(mode)` test.

Comment: That looks like proper usage of placement `new` and the object lifetime rules for reuse of object memory should definitely be kicking in.  Obviously in C++, the keyword `struct` would tend to appear a lot less, but I'd be very surprised if that makes any difference to clang.  I do still disagree with your explanation saying that the first object is re-created.

Comment: clang is just being stupid, at any optimization level above -O1 it removes the conditional second write, and it does so even when `std::launder` is used.  https://godbolt.org/z/zbdf5arTo

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fundamentally, I don't think the authors of clang view the fact that it sometimes makes unsound optimizations as a problem.  The Standards made no attempt to forbid phony breaking "optimizations" that wouldn't have been possible under the abstractions compilers were using at the time, and the authors of clang and gcc interpreted the lack of prohibition as an invitation to adopt an abstraction model that could perform such optimizations.  When their abstraction model fails to handle the corner cases mandated by the Standard, they view that as indicating a defect in the Standard.

Comment: Permission for compilers to make optimizations is found in the "as-if" rule, which certainly determines which optimizations are or are not sound.  The "breaking optimizations" are only allowed where UB is present.  Behavior dictated by the standard for well-formed code IS a prohibition on any abstraction model that changes the behavior in a way that doesn't preserve the guarantees of "as-if".  As your new function doesn't cause UB, a C++ compiler shall behave as the Standard dictates.  If clang accidentally fails to do so, that is a compiler bug.  If it intentionally fails to do so,

Comment: then it is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt: For *most* language standards, an otherwise-conforming implementation that because of bugs sometimes fails to process programs as mandated would be non-conforming.  According to the published Rationale for the C99 Standard, however, "The belief was that it is simply not practical to provide a specification which is strong enough to be useful, but which still allows for real-world problems such as bugs."  I don't know of any published Rationale for any version of the C++ Standard, so I have no idea if it has a similar attitude, but I find that attitude weird.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Otherwise, the notion that otherwise-defined actions should be characterized as UB so as to allow optimizations under the as-if rule is fundamentally broken.  There are many situations where ti would be acceptable for programs to behave in *some* ways that are observably inconsistent with sequentially processing steps as written, but where completely arbitrary behavior would not be.  As a simple example, saying that side-effect-free endless loops invoke UB won't allow as many useful optimizations as saying that execution of a loop need only be regarded as sequenced before...

Comment: ...code that is statically reachable from a single exit point if some *individual action* within the loop is observably sequenced.  If erroneous input could cause a program to hang in a computation whose results would never end up being used, and if it would be acceptable for such input to result in the program hanging or skipping the computation, a "side-effect free loops are unsequenced" rule would allow useful optimizations within a correct program meeting those requirements.  A rule that requires programmers to add dummy side effects to potentially endless loops, however, would not.